# Is it possible to do if(Object)

Tags: java

So I was wondering if it was possible to have a custom class that has a boolean value.

And in your main program you can do:

```
if(CustomClassVariable){

}
```

Like the Boolean class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Anything inside a condition in Java must be strictly a `boolean` value. The class `Boolean` works because of auto-boxing.

Comment: Can I create a custom auto-box?

Comment: I know Boolean is final, but can I create a class that auto-boxes like Boolean but doesn't work with Boolean like extending?

Comment: no, to the best of my knowledge autoboxed classes get special treatment at compile time

Answer (score 0):

only you can do like this

```
    Boolean customClassVariable = Boolean.TRUE;
    if(customClassVariable) {
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing is the process by which a primitive type is encapsulated into its equivalent object automatically.In java, the condition you give inside if should be of boolean type.
You can also give an object of Boolean type,java will unbox it to boolean type automatically.You cant create a custom class and ask java to autobox it to boolean.